# How to display image in HTML Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, image

I have a simple HTML  page with a Button. Onclick it should show an image through an Ajax call.

It works fine in Postman Rest Client.

But in browser it is showing raw data instead of pic.

HTML

```
<html>
   <button type="button" id="test" onclick="asset();"> Show Asset </button>
   <div class="result"></div>    
</html>
```

Ajax

```
$("#test").on("click", function asset() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',

    url: 'https://url', //get an image
  //url: 'https://url', //get audio file

    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'image/png');
        //xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'audio/x-wav');
    },

    success: function(data) {

        $(".result").html(data);

    },
    error: function(e) {
        alert("error post" + JSON.stringify(e));
    }
});
});
```

Sample Raw data -

```
�PNG  IHDR�O^�fsRGB���gAMA���a    pHYs���o�d�mIDATx^��{TUG����3���%c�N�8������N'��;Iw'�yu�_�Q�((�����(�E@T@��%B$$�ݝd�����I�$w�xn��3�[_�9ך�Zk��^��Wc
```

What should I do to get image?

Question 2.
How to display/play an audio/video in html page? As of now when I use another audio url...nothing gets disaplyed in browser.

---edit---
@Everyone thank you for your quick solutions. 
Actually I also need to send an HTTP Header along with the URL.
Because the URL may give me an Image/Audio/Video file depending on the Request Header.

In this case how can I display Image/Audio/Video within Webpage?

Comment: What is the type of data returned by the url ? A file ? A string ?

Comment: If your `url` is just a link to image then no need to make an `ajax` call. Just add a `img` tag to your `html` and modify its `src` attribute value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your url is just a link to image then no need to make an ajax call. Just add a `img` tag to your html and modify its `src` attribute value.

```js
var url = "https://placehold.it/350x150"; // some url

$(function(){
  $("#test").click(function(){
    $("#imgId").attr("src",url);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
   <button type="button" id="test"> Show Asset </button>
   <div class="result">
    <img id="imgId" src="" />
   </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution, one similar query, my URL may give me an Image/Audio/Video file depending on the Request Header.

In this case how can I display Audio/Video within HTML page?

Comment: Use the appropriate `html` tag and it should work fine.

Comment: Where should I mention the request header? Accept audio/x-wav in the code?

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30330856/how-do-i-play-audio-returned-from-an-xmlhttprequest-using-the-html5-audio-api

Comment: Yeah I have tried that solution, it did not work. Nothing happens onclick

Comment: It's difficult to answer your question without looking at your code. May be you can ask another question with proper code for this case. Also check the `console` if `onclick` logs some error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137126/discussion-between-john-seen-and-vatsal).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use ajax to load images, images are already loaded asynchronously. So just create an `img` element and add the src of the image. This works even when the page has been loaded.

```
$("#test").click(function() {
    $(".result").append("<img src='img/src.png' />");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `data` in `success` is a `base64 encoded image`. In that case you have to show it like:

```
success: function(data) {
    document.getElementById('img').setAttribute( 'src', data );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe image that is returned from api is base64 format. So you must convert that base64 data into image. Change your `success` callback like the following.

```
   success: function(data) {
     var img= new Image();
     img.src = 'data:image/png;base64,'+ data;
     $(".result").appendChild(img);
     }
```